# How can I run Trimmomatic to do the trimming of Paired End reads?

Tags: java, linux, jar, conda, unzip

I want to do trimming for my forward and reverse reads (paired-end reads), I have already assigned them to R1 and R2 for the input, but when I run the following command;

```
java -jar trimmomatic-0.39.jar PE $read1 $read2 \
lib3.trimmed.paired.R1.fastq.gz lib3.trimmed.unpaired.R1.fastq.gz \
lib3.trimmed.paired.R2.fastq.gz lib3.trimmed.unpaired.R2.fastq.gz \
ILLUMINACLIP:TruSeq3-PE.fa:2:30:10:2:True LEADING:3 TRAILING:3 \
MINLEN:36
```

This is what is produced;

```
Error: Unable to access jar file trimmomatic-0.39.jar
```

what can I do to proceed, I have run this command

```
conda create -c conda-forge --override-channels -n trimmomatic openjdk
```

I went ahead to run this command;

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/usadellab/Trimmomatic/main/adapters/TruSeq3-PE.fa
```

to download the trimmomatic-0.39.zip file.  It failed to download on a Linux terminal.  I had to copy the url and pasted it in a web browser and the file downloaded to my downloads folder on the windows system. I run a windows subsystem for Linux, but since I wanted that file on a linux system, I run this command to tranfer it to a folder on linux which I had named metagenomics; I endured i was in root and ran this command; `cd mnt/c/Users/Student/Downloads` and now got the zipped file to linux with this command;

```
mv Trimmomatic-0.39.zip ~/metagenomicsi
```

I ran cd to go back to home directory.

I went to unzip the Trimmomatic-0.39.zip folder which has the .jar file. I ran the `conda activate Trimmomatic` command and later `conda deactive` command but still when I ran this command;

```
java -jar trimmomatic-0.39.jar PE $read1 $read2 \
lib3.trimmed.paired.R1.fastq.gz lib3.trimmed.unpaired.R1.fastq.gz \
lib3.trimmed.paired.R2.fastq.gz lib3.trimmed.unpaired.R2.fastq.gz \
ILLUMINACLIP:TruSeq3-PE.fa:2:30:10:2:True LEADING:3 TRAILING:3 \
MINLEN:36
```

It can't run as expected, I need help.

Comment: *"I have already assigned them to R1 and R2 for the input"*. I don't see `$R1` or `$R2` anywhere, I do see `$read1` and `$read2`. Update your code sample if you really mean `$R1` or please explain the difference in the body of your question. It is best to leave out narrations in your question, "and then I did this, and then i did that", just show you code and the exact text of error error messages. **Bold** text isn't usually needed if you are providing proper spacing between paragraphs and sentences and code. Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse selected text to fmt as `code/data`

Comment: *Error: Unable to access jar file trimmomatic-0.39.jar* Do you *have* a jar of that name in the current directory?

Comment: Make your question so it is easy for readers that are interested to copy/paste code into their environment and get the same error messages you are getting. This may require including relevent env vars from various places in your environment. (A script, or a sourced shell file with env vars etc, just get the vars that affect your problem ; `set | grep JAVA` may be a place to start). Welcome to Stack Overflow (-; ! Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to run manually via JAR if you use the Bioconda version. I.e.,

```bash
$ mamba create -yn trim -c conda-forge -c bioconda trimmomatic
$ conda activate trim
(trim) $ trimmomatic    
Usage: 
       PE [-version] [-threads <threads>] [-phred33|-phred64] [-trimlog <trimLogFile>] [-summary <statsSummaryFile>] [-quiet] [-validatePairs] [-basein <inputBase> | <inputFile1> <inputFile2>] [-baseout <outputBase> | <outputFile1P> <outputFile1U> <outputFile2P> <outputFile2U>] <trimmer1>...
   or: 
       SE [-version] [-threads <threads>] [-phred33|-phred64] [-trimlog <trimLogFile>] [-summary <statsSummaryFile>] [-quiet] <inputFile> <outputFile> <trimmer1>...
   or: 
       -version
```